# Popup window in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, popup

In Javascript, I want to open my `window.html` file in a popup window. But it doesn't display any text. Just a blank page.

This is index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

  <script language="javascript">
    var newwindow;

    function popit(url){
      newwindow = window.open(
          url, '', "status=yes, height=500; width=500; resizeable=0");
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="javascript:popit(window.html);">CLICK ME!</a>
</body>
</html>
```

window.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <p>SAMPLE TEXT</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Why doesn't it display any text?

Comment: A lot of browser block popups...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
javascript:popit(window.html);
```

Replace with:

```
javascript:popit('window.html');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your click handler code is syntactically incorrect:

```
<a href="#" onclick="popit('window.html');">CLICK ME!</a>
```

Always, always have your developer console open to check for JavaScript errors! (*edit* — actually in this case there wouldn't have been an error; `window.html` would resolve to `undefined` probably! Still, keep the console open :-)

Also note that I used an "onclick" attribute instead of "href".

Answer (score 0):

**A GOOD working code with NO crashes.**

Simple and **what makes this code better** is that you can use it in a JavaScript file separately and have it fairing to more then one file with the same popup size even though its different pages on popups.

**Javascript**

```
// Popup window code
function MyPopUp(url) {
    popupWindow = window.open(
        url,'popUpWindow','height=454,width=580,left=0,top=200,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes')
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="JavaScript:MyPopUp('MyDirectory/Page.html');" title="My PopUp For You">My PopUp</a>
```

**NOTE:** You can also use this as onload in body for example `<body onload="JavaScript:MyPopUp('MyDirectory/Page.html');">` and it will aslo work on `onmouseover` and others... though I do not advise this unless you want to piss off the clients visiting your page.